# Метод и cshtml-представление работают через адресную строку, но ссылка вызывает ошибку http 404

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, http

Если в общем, решил я в учебных  целях написать программу, эмулирующую работу книжного магазина. Чтобы при запуске программы на экране появлялся список книг и рядом с каждой  книгой было слово "купить", при нажатии на которое на   экран выходила форма для оформления покупки. В общем, я сделал такую  программу. А потом я захотел улучшить ее таким образом, чтобы  при нажатии на ссылку рядом с именем  книги выходило сначала описание  книги,  а  ниже  этого описания была бы  ссылка для оформления покупки.Создал новый  проект, и короче у меня там даже дебаггинг не работал(Возможно ,это было потому,  потому что у меня не  была  обновлена лицензия на бесплатную Visual Studio Community .) Создал еще  третий проект , поменял код в файле  Index.cshtml,  и кроме заглавия этого списка книг у меня ничего не появилось. Долго не мог понять, в чем дело  ,вернулся  к  старому  проекту и поначалу смог  добиться того только,   что у меня рядом с ссылкой "Купить " появилась ссылка" Описание ",и все отлично работало  благодаря соответствующим методам, на которые ссылались эти ссылки. Я захотел перенести это  на свой третий проект  и вспомнил, что я забыл  инициализировать базу данных в Global.asax(Я использовал во всех этих проектах подход CodeFirst . При этой методике сама Visual Studio  создает  базу данных и не нужно создавать ее предварительно в SQL Studio .). Я  инициализировал   базу данных вот такой строкой

```
        Database.SetInitializer(new BookDbInitializer());
```

Класс  BookDbInitializer, расширяющий   DropCreateDatabaseAlways, я тоже перед этим создал. И в  третьем проекте у меня получилось, что через  адресную строку  метод  BookView у меня работает, а через ссылку"  Описание" -нет. При этом мне удалось сделать в представлении  BookView  ссылку на метод,  который выводит на экран  форму для оформления покупки именно той книги , на ссылку рядом с которой я нажал в   представлении Index . Вот вам код  моего представления  BookView   из моего третьего проекта (Который вообще-то называется  BookStoreFour.):

```
 @{

            /**/


            Layout = null;
             }

              <!DOCTYPE html>

               <html>
               <head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
                 <title>BookView</title>
                  </head>
                  <body>
                   <div>


    @model BookStoreFour.Models.Book

    <h2>Книга № @Model.Id</h2><!-- Принимает значение поступившее в параметр метода  BookView и выводит его на экран.-->
    @Html.Display("Description")
    <p><a href="/Home/Buy/@Model.Id">Купить</a></p> <!-- Принимает значение поступившее в параметр метода  BookView и передает его в метод Buy.-->
    <!--<p>Html.ActionLink("Купить", " Buy", "Home", new { id = Model.Id }, null)</p>-->
</div>
  </body>
   </html>
```

Потом я переделал свой самый первый проект по примеру этого  BookStoreFour,   только при этом    метод  BookView  у меня в этом первом первом проекте работает и через адресную строку ,и через  нажатие ссылки" Описание", а в  BookStoreFour- только через адресную строку.При этом в этом   BookStoreFour у меня при нажатии "Описание" в  адресной строке после имени контроллера и слеша появляется %20  ,а в моем самом первом проекте ничего такого нет... Кто-нибудь может подсказать, отчего все так?  В своем последнем проекте я уже нажимал" Перестроить проект"  и  "Очистить проект "(У меня русскоязычный  интерфейс.) .Никакого толку. Еще я забыл сказать,  что как раз при нажатии на" Описание" в моем самом последнем проекте у меня и выходит ошибка Http 404. Не удалось найти данный ресурс и все такое (Запускаю я при этом не из cshtml-файла.). Я работаю в ASP.NET MVC4.

Comment: Стоооолько лишней информации, ради простого `в адресной строке после имени контроллера и слеша появляется %20`, жуть... По вопросу - на сколько мне известно, `%20` - это пробел. Вот его и ищите лишний у себя в коде. Например вот `" Buy"` - это конечно не он, но скорей всего где то у вас имеется такой же "косяк".

Comment: Заходим через Хром или Фокс, копируем адресную строку Crtl+C, втавляем в блокнот Ctrl+V. Полученую строку - вставляем в браузер - работает? Если да - используйте именно такую комбинацию символов, вы чуть неправильно "понимаете" что такое адресная строка (некоторые символы заменяются на комбинацию %код, а браузеры в 2000х годах решили что нужно жить в новом веке, и стали отображать символы а не коды символов - называется URL-кодирование), если нет - у вас суперуникальный случай.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще у меня получился цирк. Проблема была не в том представлении BookView, код которого я в этот вопрос выложил, а действительно в том , что в Index- представлении в ссылке  после имени контроллера и слеша у меня был пробел.Глупо получилось... Ну, по крайней мере теперь и я и другие посетители форума будут иметь возможность узнать отсюда, что если в адресной строке после имени контроллера и слеша появляется %20, то это значит что где-то в коде рядом с именем метода есть пробел. Спасибо за комментарий  EvgeniyZ.